# Reading from one byte file returns 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD

Tags: java, byte, fileinputstream

**Solved**, accepted answer below because it pointed me at checking how my file got corrupted. Please read the end of this question for the Maven reason.

I created a 1-byte file containing the byte `0xA8`. I'm trying to read it into any Java structure that will allow me to work with it later. I know bytes in java are signed so any value from `0x80` through `0xFF` will be interpreted negative.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        // 0xA8.hex contains one byte 0xA8.
        final File inputFile = new File(Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource("0xA8.hex").getPath());
        final FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        final DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fin);
        int read = dis.readUnsignedByte();
        System.out.println(read + ", hex: " + Integer.toHexString(read));

        while (true) {
            try {
                read = dis.readUnsignedByte();
                System.out.println("read more: " + read + ", hex: " + Integer.toHexString(read));
            } catch (final EOFException ignored) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There probably is something *really* simple I'm missing, but I can't wrap my head around it.. The program above outputs:

```
239, hex: ef
read more: 191, hex: bf
read more: 189, hex: bd
```

The `0xA8.hex` file is a 1-byte file I created myself using a hex editor. The contents of it really is one single byte:

```
drvdijk@macmine:~/$ hexdump 0xA8.hex 
0000000 a8                                             
0000001
```

Why, and how can I make it read just one (possibly cast to unsigned) byte?

## Solution

I use Maven, and in the `pom.xml` I had a section:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <!-- ... -->
</build>
```

The `0xA8.hex` file I was using got filtered by Maven, entering the replacement character (0xEF 0xBF 0xBD) where my `0xA8` used to be. I now updated the `pom.xml` to the following:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.hex</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.hex</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <!-- ... -->
</build>
```

Comment: It seems like the first bytes are the BOM-Header of the file (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Open your file with an Hexeditor and you will see it.

Comment: Is that really a binary file? How is the byte written in the first place?

Comment: The comment `// 0xA8.hex contains one byte 0xA8.` is wrong. Your file does not contain just one byte of 0xA8 - you'll need to prove that it does.

Comment: Thanks guys, but the `0xA8.hex` file is a file I created myself using a hex editor, it really contains only one single byte. Updated the question accordingly.
This is a contrived example (I did code this and verified its output for this question though), in real life I'm trying to read some proprietary little-endian file format.

Comment: I just tried the program and it displays the expected output: `168, hex: a8`.

Comment: You guys (specifically @nos) are right, it's *not* the file I made myself it is reading, but rather a maven-processed resource file. *doh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your file is having replacement character http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=65280&utf8=dec

```
U+FFFD  �   239 191 189 REPLACEMENT CHARACTER
```

Not the `0xA8` , i did created one simple file using the following code

```
File f = new File("0xA8.hex");
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        stream.write(0xA8);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
```

Note** just for demo

And used your program to read it is working as excepted. Find how the file corrupted .

Comment: Wauw, you are right! The file I think I'm reading is not the file I'm reading! The `Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource("0xA8.hex").getPath()` in my code does not point to the file I made using my text editor, but rather to Maven-filtered test-resource. Again, wauw.